# Getting curl response from CLI but access denied from PHP

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

For many requests I am getting access denied errors when using curl from php, my code is:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.vueling.com/en');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '2');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $data;
```

which returns this:

```
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
```

However if I run it directly on the command line:

```
curl -v https://www.vueling.com/en
```

I get the full response, my ip is not blocked, im not sure why CLI works but PHP doesnt? Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The CLI version of `curl` probably send an user agent that is accepted by this website, but the PHP version lay send an user agent that is rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLI version of `curl` probably sends an user agent that is accepted by this website, but the PHP version of curl may send an user agent that is rejected.

So you have to check that the headers sent by curl are similar in both ways.